# sharepoint dateandtime field get hours

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am trying to get hours from the DateandTime field of a sharepoint calendar listitem using sharepoint Object Model.

int starttime = Convert.ToInt32(item["Start Time"]);

Obviously which returns type error.

Please throw some light that how i can pick Time value from the field and convert to Int.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DateTime starttime = Convert.ToDateTime(item["Start Time"]);
```

From there, you have a number of time [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_properties.aspx) ([Hour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx), [Millisecond](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond.aspx), [Minute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minute.aspx), [Second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.second.aspx)) that are integers.